# Javascript outputting array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

Can't really figure out why I cant get the values that I have passed through an AJAX call in my javascript function.

[image]

As seen in the picture, msg is the array that's passed from the backend to the javascript function
I've tried both

```
info['taxarray'].forEach() and info.taxarray.forEach()
```

Console.log(info.taxarray) works fine and it outputs the array in the console, but when I try to run iterations through this array, I can't access the values in it, I'm sure I'm missing something, but I can't figure out what it is.

[image]

This is the output for the console

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Please share all information in text form. Also, please explain how this is related to PHP

Comment: info.taxarray.forEach(taxArr => {
taxArr.forEach(tax=> console.log(tax.tax_values))
}).
taxarray is an array of arrays as sohaieb said.

Comment: Please avoid pictures of code. They can't be copy-pasted. Use code formatting instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can flatten the multidimensional array with `flat` method:

```
info.flat().forEach(item => console.log(item.tax))
```

Using `flatmap` it gets even more straightforward

```
info.flatMap(item => console.log(item.tax))
```

Comment: what would be the difference between those two? how would the output would look for each one. I implemented flat() so it looks like info.taxarray.flat().forEach(function (taxes){
console.log(taxes.tax);
});

Comment: [`It is identical to a map() followed by a flat() of depth 1, but slightly more efficient than calling those two methods separately.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Answer (score 3):

As i can see, your `info.taxarray` is a **multidementional array** so that's **every element** inside it is also an **another array**.
your `console.log(info.taxarray)` gives see :

```
[Array(1), Array(1)]
```

to access **tax_values** of the first element you have to write `info.taxarray[0][0].tax_values` so that means you have to iterate the **taxarray** and also it's elements (which are arrays too) .
Check your code.
you can also refer to [the solution of Mike Ezzati](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66698895/8678900) it help a lot

Comment: God that was a stupid mistake by me, THANK YOU !

Answer (score 1):

the response you get seems to be multidimensional (an array of arrays each of which has only one element)

```
info.taxarray.forEach(msg) { (item) => {
    console.log(item[0].tax_values)
}};
```

OR if array elements can be more so iterate again

```
info.taxarray.forEach(msg) { (item) => {
    item.forEach(msg) { (item) => {
        console.log(i.tax_values)
    }};
}};
```